# How to save Duration into H2 database

Tags: java, h2, duration

I want to save duration of audio file into H2 database. I found that there is java.time.Duration class and it looks like something I would want to use. The problem is that I cannot find if H2 database supports Duration (or some mapping into timestamp for example). So is there a way to use it this way? Or do I have to somehow do it with LocalDateTime/DateTime? I was also considering saving seconds as integer and then just formating it for output.

Thanks for answer in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The full list of types supported by H2 can be found [here](http://www.h2database.com/html/datatypes.html).

There is no specific type for duration, so I would recommend instead using either an `INT` or `DECIMAL` type, depending on the precision you need, and to make sure that the column name indicates the unit (ex. `DURATION_SEC`).

While one could technically use the `TIME` type, I would not recommend this as, by convention, this field means "time of day" rather than "duration".

Comment: Yes, I found that list too, thank you. TIME and TIMESTAMP types where those missleading types that I thought there might exist some kind of mapping for.